# What is this: `impl<T> Trait for T {}`?

Tags: rust, traits

Recently, I saw different places where this was given as example code, and writing it in my editor, it seems to be valid code.

```rust
trait Trait {}

impl<T> Trait for T {}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation explaining this; I'm sure it exists, but I don't really know what to google.

How would you instantiate `T` to and then call any methods within the impl block?

I'm sure there is a good reason for this, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it, would anyone be able to link the relevant documentation for this feature in rust?

---

I realise from the answers that I may have not been clear; I had copied the example from what I’ve seen.

Though from the first answer, I realised that the below code is also valid, and perhaps a more clear representation of what I’m trying to ask, which is, what is the use for the generics syntax that allows this code to be valid:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn test() -> String {
        "test".to_string()
    }
}

impl<T> Trait for T {}
```

Does this affect existing structs and enums in the file, or does it literally just do absolutely nothing, and can never be called or used?

Comment: Not all legal code _has_ a practical use; sometimes things are examples that need to be extended (in this case, by defining actual concrete types) before they have utility. Note, though, that all Stack Overflow questions _are expected to be practical in nature_, about a "specific problem you actually face". Certainly, a trait itself is not a thing that _can_ be instantiated on its own. `impl trait` lets you define functions that called with anything implementing that trait, but you still need a concrete type for any particular such "anything" to be before instantiation can take place.

Comment: The code in your edit isn't valid, so it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: @interjay Ah yes, you are right, rust-analyzer was being slow, i've updated the edit section, this code definitely does compile and run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is showing you two things: marker traits and blanket implementations.

`trait Foo {}` (with no trait members) declares a *marker trait* which serves only to tag certain types.  The built-in traits `Copy`, `Send`, and `Sync` are good examples of marker traits.

`impl<T> Foo for T {}` implements the trait `Foo` for all types, a so-called *blanket implementation.*

Together, this is pretty much redundant, because there isn't a difference between "type that implements `Foo`" and "all types."

However, seemingly-useless blanket implementations can actually be useful in practice.  In the Rust standard library, there is a blanket implementation `impl<T> From<T> for T` which tells Rust "you can convert any `T` to `T`."  This is not useful on its own, but winds up being useful in generic code, such as `fn foo(arg: impl Into<i32>)` which lets you pass an argument of any type that can be infallibly converted to `i32`.  **Because of the blanket implementation, this includes `i32` itself.**

> How would you instantiate `T` to then call any methods within the impl block?

Well, the body of the `impl` block can't have anything in this case.  The body of an `impl ... for` block is to implement trait members, but the trait being implemented has no members.

If we assume that the trait *does* have members, then the answer to your question would be that you would have to bound `T` in a way that lets you perform operations on it.  For example, to create a `T` you could choose to add the bound `T: Default` which would let you call `T::default()` to create an instance of `T` with a (type-defined) default value.

Note that adding bounds on `T` would change the scope of the implementation to only apply to types that satisfy the bounds.  This is very common in practice.  For example, the implementation of `Clone` on `Vec<T>` is bounded on `T: Clone`.  (How would you clone a vector if you can't clone its elements, after all?)

---

Further reading:

- [The Rust Programming Language - Traits: Defining Shared Behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Comment: Hi, this is a really good answer, but you made me realise I probably hadn't made my question clear enough, so i've added an edit, thanks!

Comment: @StefanKyriacou The answer to that question is different. The `T: Default` bound isn't necessary and doesn't really accomplish anything. Both Rust and English have a grammar, and you can construct useless but grammatically-correct sentences in both. The `impl` block applies to all types that implement `Default`, even though nothing ever uses the `Default` implementation.

Comment: Yes, I now realise that adding the Default constraint is different, the specific thing I was looking for was the term "blanket implementation", that's the part I was missing, and is the very last part of the link you provided, plus your answer was all round very helpful, so i'm going to mark it as the answer, thank you!